# Sending Event to 3rd Party

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to send an event/alert to an external source in pine-script? This would include writing to a file or sending some sort of message to a 3rd party bot.

If so, does anyone have an example of how to do this?   Big picture, I am trying to send a signal to a third party execution system (not a broker).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can.
TradingView (TV) offers the following options for communicating alerts with the external world:

- Notify on TV app
- Show popup (TV website)
- Send Email
- **Webhook URL (<< paid subscription necessary)**
- Play sound
- Send Email-to-SMS

You can create such alerts also based on your own Study scripts with the function `alertcondition()`.

For details, please see:

1. [alertcondition function on Pine-script reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_alertcondition)
2. [alertcondition on Pine-script manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Alert_conditions.html?highlight=alert)

For hooking up with bots, we're particularly interested in the webhook connector.
Here, you can make TV send an HTTP POST message to whatever URL you want, and from there you can trigger your bot on your server side to do whatever you want.
Note that such HTTP POST messages can by customized a lot, so the message can carry a lot of instructions to your bot to minimize custom work on the bot side.
A nice to have is a server on cloud service premises, so don't have to bother about  availability, connectivity and ever-changing IP addresses.

I strongly recommend you to have a look on this:

[Tradingview webhook bot in Python](https://github.com/Robswc/tradingview-webhooks-bot)

This open-source python connector uses Flask to set up a webserver where TV will send HTTP POST messages to. Within the environment, ccxt* package is used in order to offer you a broad selection of (crypto) exchanges.

If you're interested in non-crypto stuff, then you need something to play the role of ccxt and make sure you can connect to your broker API endpoints.

*: [link to CCXT on github](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt)

Comment: Thanks Glauco.  This information is well organized and very helpful.   Here is another reference that I came across that could be useful for anyone with the same questions.  It is from Pine Coders:  https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#automated-order-execution